# How to create a user with email as login using Graph API in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am implementing Azure B2C in my ASP MVC application.
My sign up policy has email account chosen so If a user sign up, his account is created and he can log in using his email (I mean private email like xxx@gmail).

If I look at old azure portal -> users section, for this particular user there is no meaningfull data, just objectId. Where the email he provided is stored? (alternate mail field is empty).

And here starts my real question.

I would like also add users via Graph API. I am doing this via GraphConsoleAppV3 sample application. However I cannot set the mail field, the only thing I can do is add the email (custom email like @gmail) to the 'OtherEmails' collection.

But adding the user this way,  I cannot log in to my application using private email. I can login using UPN name but I do not want to. Users will not know the UPN,  only they real emails.

I can see in the Internet samples with something like 'SignInNames' but iin PowerShell.

I would like to set the user via Graph API and indicate that it has email as login type - not UPN. Hot to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that there is  other sample project to create users in B2C (via posts with json). It seems that to sync B2C with AD and entire graph will take a while and all the nomenclature needs to unified

Comment: can you please share the sample project

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, and this is from ages ago, but this may help someone in the future.

If you want to create a user in B2C through the Microsoft Graph API in C#, with an email as their sign-in, you can do the following:
**NOTE:** This is assuming you already setup the Microsoft Graph API in your C# application. If you have not done that yet, you can follow [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad).

First Create the user and the Identities.

```C#
 public async Task CreateUser(string username, string givenName, string email, string password)
        {
            var identities = CreateIdentities(username, email, new List<ObjectIdentity>());
            var user = new User
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
                DisplayName = username,
                GivenName = givenName,
                Identities = identities,
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                    Password = password
                }
            };

            var response = await userRepository.CreateUserRequest(user);
        }
```

When creating the Identities make sure the email and username are not the exact same values.

```C#
private List<ObjectIdentity> CreateIdentities(string username, string email, List<ObjectIdentity> identities)
        {
            if (email != null) identities = AddIdentity(identities, "emailAddress", email);
            
            if (username != null && (!username.Equals(email) || email == null)) identities = AddIdentity(identities, "userName", username);

            return identities;
        }
```

```C#
  /// <summary>
        /// Adds an Identity to the ObjectIdentity list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="identities">List of identities</param>
        /// <param name="signInType">Type of sign-in, which is mostly just emailAddress or userName</param>
        /// <param name="issuerAssignedId">The value of the sign-in name or email, for example t.chermin@please.nl</param>
        /// <returns>List of ObjectIdentity</returns>
        private List<ObjectIdentity> AddIdentity(List<ObjectIdentity> identities, string signInType, string issuerAssignedId)
        {
            var identity = new ObjectIdentity
            {
                SignInType = signInType,
                Issuer = issuer,
                IssuerAssignedId = issuerAssignedId
            };
            identities.Add(identity);
            return identities;
        }
```

Finally, we can add the user to our AADB2C environment:

```C#
 public async Task<User> CreateUserRequest(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                return await graphClient.Users
                 .Request()
                 .AddAsync(user);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
            return null;
        }
```